# Copy (command-c) adds to clipboard. How to disable?

Tags: macos, clipboard, textmate

Since a while a copy action (command-c) adds the current selection to the clipboard instead of replacing the clipboard.

This mostly happens while coding in TextMate but also happened in CSSedit. The action makes a distinct "click" sound. This does not happen every time I do a copy and it drives me insane. I've searched the interwebs but could not find a solution.

Comment: Probably should be moved to superuser.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/resources/launchbar/help/index.php?chapter=ClipboardHistory) or something similar?

Comment: Yes I use Launchbar... disabling the ClipMerge option fixed it (hopefully). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/)'s clipboard merging feature:
[image]

It states that it should only be triggered when C is pressed twice, so I will have to check my keyboard whether the C-Key triggers twice. Since this never happens when writing text, it may also be a bug in Alfred.